# How to omit argument name in a struct

Tags: swift, struct, parameters

Swift beginner here... When passing a value into a struct instance during instantiation, is there a way to omit the argument name? I can't find anything in Swift documentation.

```swift
struct Dog {
    var _ name: String
}

var buddy = Dog("Buddy")
```

Obviously this does not work. In functions you can use an underscore before the parameter name to omit it during calling, is this possible in some way with structs?

Comment: You can write your own [initialiser](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID207), but why don't you want the argument label? It is very useful in telling you what the parameter is for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Properties always have names. What can differ are the keyword labels of the initializer. If you don't specify your own initializer, the compiler will synthesize a default [*memberwise initializer*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID213) for you, which will have argument labels that match the member names.

If you wish to change that, you would forego the compiler-provided initializer, and specify your own:

```
struct Dog {
    var name: String

    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```